# react native modal status bar is white not transparent

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, expo

I use this libary for my modal:

https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize

if I open the modal, my statusbar is white. How can I make this transparent ?

Comment: Any updates on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Please use **statusBarTranslucent**. This will solve your problem perfectly.

This has added since React Native 0.62

```
<Modal {...props} statusBarTranslucent>...</Modal>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use `react-native-modal` and I have the same issue.

This library doesn't completely hide the status bar but makes it transparent instead of white. No codes required. You just need to link the library and it works.

https://github.com/listenzz/react-native-modal-translucent